# Not able to display data on HTML table

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am not able to display data on HTML Table this is my HTML code. I have tried to use JavaScript to update table without refreshing the page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OBD-2 Data Display</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        table {
            margin: auto;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 2px solid black;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: white;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #e6e6e6;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Enter your input:</h2>
    <form id="submit-form">
        <label for="input">Input:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_input" id="input"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h1>OBD-2 Data Display</h1>
        <table id="data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Parameter</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="data-table-body">
                {% for key, value in data.items() %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ key }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit-form").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting normally

                // get the form data
                var form_data = $(this).serialize();

                // submit the form data via AJAX
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/",
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        // update the table with the new data
                        console.log(data)
                        $("#data-table-body").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my python code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
   data = {}  # initialize an empty dictionary for data
   if request.method == 'POST':
      user_input = request.form['user_input']
      # do something with user_input to get the OBD-II data
      a = user_input.upper()
      y = packet_splitter(a)
      data = flatten_dict(finaldic)
      print(data)
      return jsonify(data)
  return render_template('template.html', data=data)
```

The data after converting will look like this:

```py
data = {'name':"Jhon",'surname':"smith",'age':"23"}
```

So I pass this dictionary in the HTML template but it does not able to display data but when I see in browser console I can see the data.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What happens when you debug?  Are there any errors at all in the development console when using the browser's debugging tools?  In those tools, on the network tab, was the AJAX request made to the server?  What was the server's response?

Comment: there is no error in the development console. and I can see the log data on the console and server response is 200

Comment: What is the exact data that gets logged to the console?  Does it *have* a `.data` property?

Comment: no, it does not have a .data property I was just trying different possibilities I have updated the code I am only passing data

Comment: Why are you just calling $("#data-table-body").html(data); and setting it to data? If you're calling the post request and then setting the html of #data-table-body to the dictionary, it's not going to update the table, it's just going to put the data in plain text where the table was.

Comment: check your console very well for other errors or the home function. I did this:

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    data = {'name': "Jhon", 'surname': "smith", 'age': "23"}
    print(data)

    return render_template('template.html', data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

using the html you provided, it worked fine. Returned like so below:

OBD-2 Data Display
Parameter Value
name Jhon
surname smith
age 23

Comment: @DoghorSamuel If we pass a static dictionary then it will display on a table, but when I do post a request, the problem arises.It does not show on table

Comment: @walker then how should I pass data to the table do you have any other idea?